# RTL8822CE BT-WiFi module not listing bluetooth devices during scaning. But WiFi working perfectly

Tags: drivers, bluetooth

I am using NVIDIA Jetson TX2 NX with WiFi-BT Module based on RTL8822ce chip.
Bluetooth can open and see every detail, but when start the scan, it will not list nearby devices.

```
[NEW] Controller 70:66:55:A6:F4:72 BlueZ 5.48 [default]
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# show
Controller 70:66:55:A6:F4:72 (public)
    Name: BlueZ 5.48
    Alias: BlueZ 5.48
    Class: 0x00000000
    Powered: yes
    Discoverable: no
    Pairable: yes
    UUID: Generic Attribute Profile (00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: PnP Information           (00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Generic Access Profile    (00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    Modalias: usb:v1D6Bp0246d0530
    Discovering: no
[bluetooth]# discoverable on
Changing discoverable on succeeded
[CHG] Controller 70:66:55:A6:F4:72 Discoverable: yes
[bluetooth]# show
Controller 70:66:55:A6:F4:72 (public)
    Name: BlueZ 5.48
    Alias: BlueZ 5.48
    Class: 0x00000000
    Powered: yes
    Discoverable: yes
    Pairable: yes
    UUID: Generic Attribute Profile (00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: PnP Information           (00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Generic Access Profile    (00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    Modalias: usb:v1D6Bp0246d0530
    Discovering: no
[bluetooth]# scan on
Discovery started
[CHG] Controller 70:66:55:A6:F4:72 Discovering: yes
[bluetooth]# scan off
[CHG] Controller 70:66:55:A6:F4:72 Discovering: no
Discovery stopped
[bluetooth]# exit
Agent unregistered
[DEL] Controller 70:66:55:A6:F4:72 BlueZ 5.48 [default]
```

But when I take the log, I noticed some issues in HCI Command order.

```
root@localhost:/home/ASKC# btmon
Bluetooth monitor ver 5.48
= Note: Linux version 4.9.253-tegra (aarch64)                                                                                        0.275592
= Note: Bluetooth subsystem version 2.22                                                                                             0.275595
= New Index: 70:66:55:A6:F4:72 (Primary,USB,hci0)                                                                             [hci0] 0.275596
= Open Index: 70:66:55:A6:F4:72                                                                                               [hci0] 0.275597
= Index Info: 70:66:55:A6:F4:72 (Realtek Semiconductor Corporation)                                                           [hci0] 0.275598
@ MGMT Open: bluetoothd (privileged) version 1.14                                                                           {0x0002} 0.275599
@ MGMT Open: bluetoothd (privileged) version 1.14                                                                           {0x0001} 0.275601
@ MGMT Open: btmon (privileged) version 1.14                                                                                {0x0003} 0.275626
@ MGMT Command: Set Connectable (0x0007) plen 1                                                                     {0x0001} [hci0] 17.340311
        Connectable: Enabled (0x01)
@ MGMT Event: Command Complete (0x0001) plen 7                                                                      {0x0001} [hci0] 17.340407
      Set Connectable (0x0007) plen 4
        Status: Success (0x00)
        Current settings: 0x00000ad3
          Powered
          Connectable
          Bondable
          Secure Simple Pairing
          BR/EDR
          Low Energy
          Secure Connections
@ MGMT Event: New Settings (0x0006) plen 4                                                                          {0x0003} [hci0] 17.340425
        Current settings: 0x00000ad3
          Powered
          Connectable
          Bondable
          Secure Simple Pairing
          BR/EDR
          Low Energy
          Secure Connections
@ MGMT Event: New Settings (0x0006) plen 4                                                                          {0x0002} [hci0] 17.340425
        Current settings: 0x00000ad3
          Powered
          Connectable
          Bondable
          Secure Simple Pairing
          BR/EDR
          Low Energy
          Secure Connections
@ MGMT Command: Set Discoverable (0x0006) plen 3                                                                    {0x0001} [hci0] 17.340628
        Discoverable: General (0x01)
        Timeout: 180
< HCI Command: Write Current IAC LAP (0x03|0x003a) plen 4                                                                 #1 [hci0] 17.340783
        Number of IAC: 1
        Access code: 0x9e8b33 (General Inquiry)
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4                                                                               #2 [hci0] 17.341793
      Write Current IAC LAP (0x03|0x003a) ncmd 2
        Status: Success (0x00)
< HCI Command: Write Scan Enable (0x03|0x001a) plen 1                                                                     #3 [hci0] 17.341914
        Scan enable: Inquiry Scan + Page Scan (0x03)
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4                                                                               #4 [hci0] 17.342825
      Write Scan Enable (0x03|0x001a) ncmd 2
        Status: Success (0x00)
@ MGMT Event: Command Complete (0x0001) plen 7                                                                      {0x0001} [hci0] 17.342964
      Set Discoverable (0x0006) plen 4
        Status: Success (0x00)
        Current settings: 0x00000adb
          Powered
          Connectable
          Discoverable
          Bondable
          Secure Simple Pairing
          BR/EDR
          Low Energy
          Secure Connections
@ MGMT Event: New Settings (0x0006) plen 4                                                                          {0x0003} [hci0] 17.343001
        Current settings: 0x00000adb
          Powered
          Connectable
          Discoverable
          Bondable
          Secure Simple Pairing
          BR/EDR
          Low Energy
          Secure Connections
@ MGMT Event: New Settings (0x0006) plen 4                                                                          {0x0002} [hci0] 17.343001
        Current settings: 0x00000adb
          Powered
          Connectable
          Discoverable
          Bondable
          Secure Simple Pairing
          BR/EDR
          Low Energy
          Secure Connections
@ MGMT Command: Start Discovery (0x0023) plen 1                                                                     {0x0001} [hci0] 30.352194
        Address type: 0x07
          BR/EDR
          LE Public
          LE Random
< HCI Command: LE Set Random Address (0x08|0x0005) plen 6                                                                 #5 [hci0] 30.352384
        Address: 1D:0F:B3:73:FA:E7 (Non-Resolvable)
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4                                                                               #6 [hci0] 30.353773
      LE Set Random Address (0x08|0x0005) ncmd 2
        Status: Success (0x00)
< HCI Command: LE Set Scan Parameters (0x08|0x000b) plen 7                                                                #7 [hci0] 30.353889
        Type: Active (0x01)
        Interval: 11.250 msec (0x0012)
        Window: 11.250 msec (0x0012)
        Own address type: Random (0x01)
        Filter policy: Accept all advertisement (0x00)
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4                                                                               #8 [hci0] 30.354774
      LE Set Scan Parameters (0x08|0x000b) ncmd 2
        Status: Success (0x00)
< HCI Command: LE Set Scan Enable (0x08|0x000c) plen 2                                                                    #9 [hci0] 30.354871
        Scanning: Enabled (0x01)
        Filter duplicates: Enabled (0x01)
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4                                                                              #10 [hci0] 30.355763
      LE Set Scan Enable (0x08|0x000c) ncmd 2
        Status: Success (0x00)
@ MGMT Event: Command Complete (0x0001) plen 4                                                                      {0x0001} [hci0] 30.356005
      Start Discovery (0x0023) plen 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
        Address type: 0x07
          BR/EDR
          LE Public
          LE Random
@ MGMT Event: Discovering (0x0013) plen 2                                                                           {0x0003} [hci0] 30.356057
        Address type: 0x07
          BR/EDR
          LE Public
          LE Random
        Discovery: Enabled (0x01)
@ MGMT Event: Discovering (0x0013) plen 2                                                                           {0x0002} [hci0] 30.356057
        Address type: 0x07
          BR/EDR
          LE Public
          LE Random
        Discovery: Enabled (0x01)
@ MGMT Event: Discovering (0x0013) plen 2                                                                           {0x0001} [hci0] 30.356057
        Address type: 0x07
          BR/EDR
          LE Public
          LE Random
        Discovery: Enabled (0x01)
< HCI Command: LE Set Scan Enable (0x08|0x000c) plen 2                                                                   #11 [hci0] 35.626810
        Scanning: Disabled (0x00)
        Filter duplicates: Disabled (0x00)
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4                                                                              #12 [hci0] 35.627802
      LE Set Scan Enable (0x08|0x000c) ncmd 2
        Status: Success (0x00)
< HCI Command: Inquiry (0x01|0x0001) plen 5                                                                              #13 [hci0] 35.627958
        Access code: 0x9e8b33 (General Inquiry)
        Length: 5.12s (0x04)
        Num responses: 0
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4                                                                                #14 [hci0] 35.628759
      Inquiry (0x01|0x0001) ncmd 2
        Status: Success (0x00)
> HCI Event: Inquiry Complete (0x01) plen 1                                                                              #15 [hci0] 40.750766
        Status: Success (0x00)
@ MGMT Event: Discovering (0x0013) plen 2                                                                           {0x0003} [hci0] 40.750922
        Address type: 0x07
          BR/EDR
          LE Public
          LE Random
        Discovery: Disabled (0x00)
@ MGMT Event: Discovering (0x0013) plen 2                                                                           {0x0002} [hci0] 40.750922
        Address type: 0x07
          BR/EDR
          LE Public
          LE Random
        Discovery: Disabled (0x00)
@ MGMT Event: Discovering (0x0013) plen 2                                                                           {0x0001} [hci0] 40.750922
        Address type: 0x07
          BR/EDR
          LE Public
          LE Random
        Discovery: Disabled (0x00)
client_loop: send disconnect: Broken pipe
```

You can see, after scan enabling step, HCI Command: Inquiry is not sending. And when scanning disables, HCI Command: Inquiry is sending. That is, there is a difference in order of command and event sequence.

Can I change the sequence? Can you anybody help me to solve?

Answer (score 0):

We must add the device ID of our module in misc file present in the driver file.
Device ID can be get from `lsusb` command.

Also, we need to remove unwanted modules loaded in the kernel.
check using `lsmod`.